# Control how Moxy serializes and deserializes enums in a generic way

Tags: java, enums, eclipselink, marshalling, moxy

In our project, we have many enums that implement a specific interface which is a way how to control its backing in the database. The core is a method `getCode` which returns the value that is stored in the database.

*This value should be used by Moxy for both marshalling and unumarshalling.*

For instance, the enum looks as follows:

```
enum Weekday implements PersistableEnum<String> {
    MONDAY("MON"),
    // .. all the remaining days
    ;
    // the constructor which sets the code, etc.

    @Override
    public String getCode() {
         return code;
    }
}
```

by using an interface `PersistableEnum` (simplified for simplicity sake):

```
interface PersistableEnum<C> {
    C getCode();
}
```

the enum (and all others) is backed in the database by using the `code` value.

In my scenario, I need Moxy to serialize the `MONDAY` as `MON`, which is possible to achieve with

- a `@XmlEnumValue("MON")` or
- an adapter `XmlAdapter<String, Weekday>`

However, I would like to know if it's possible to provide more elegant solution which requires neither an adapter for each enum nor an additional code in the enum implementation (e.g., the `@XmlEnumValue`). 
A way that is transparently used for all enums that implement my `PersistableEnum` interface.

I had no success with an implementation of `XmlAdapter<String, PersistableEnum>` as I don't have a context of the class to be unmarshalled; and therefore, I do not know which `PersistableEnum` to use. (The marshalling part is easy to implement though.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible. I afraid that there is no such mechanism in MOXy/JAXB RI.